# Routing simulation (Distance vector)

Tags: c#, simulation, pathfinding

I am trying to write simulation for routing algorithm by distance vector. I will explain my class and how it works a bit, and then, introduce **three** main issues I encouter. Important to mention that all of it works (*but does not give fine results*). Each Router is numbered in ID's from 0 to n-1(for n routers). Router has vector table - distance vectors for every other router.(*Before we run simulation Router is initialized with its distance vector and its neighbors distance vectors*). Router also has next hop array which provides us with next hop from this router to n. **Issues and considerations**:

1. *Communicating between routers.* Object invokes get method for each of its neighbor. Is it good enough?
2. When running, I create *threads* for routers run method. Does this code can handle this?
3. *DistanceHop*. It was coded because, I need to get actual next hop by value. Maybe there is more efficient way.

Remember, this is only simulation. If you have any suggestions for change, or improvment, I would be really glad to hear that.

```
public class Router
{
    private static int _counter = -1;
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // -1 = to itself
    // -2 = does not exists
    public int[] nextHop { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, Router> neighbors { get; set; }
    public int[,] Vector { get; set; }


    public Router()
    {
        Id = System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref _counter);
    }

    // Write neighbors distance vectors to our table
    public void InitializeBeforeStart()
    {
        foreach (var neighbor in neighbors)
        {
            int id = neighbor.Key;
            for (int i = 0; i < nextHop.Length; i++)
            {
                Vector[id, i] = neighbor.Value.Vector[neighbor.Value.Id, i];
            }
        }
    }
    public void run()
    {
        BellmanFord();
    }

    // Send our distance vector to neighbors
    public void SendVector()
    {
        int[] thisVector = generateVector();
        foreach (var neighbor in neighbors)
        {
            neighbor.Value.GetVector(thisVector);
        }
    }

    // Extract our distance vector from table
    private int[] generateVector()
    {
        // just number of routers (no actual association with nextHop)
        int n = nextHop.Length;

        int[] x = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            x[i] = this.Vector[Id, i];
        }
        return x;
    }

    // Get Vector from neighbor(s)
    public void GetVector(int[] neighborVector)
    {

        // copy neighbor vector to our table
        int neighborId = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < neighborVector.Length; i++)
        {
            if (neighborVector[i] == 0) neighborId = i;
        }
        if (neighborId >= 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < neighborVector.Length; i++)
            {
                this.Vector[neighborId, i] = i;
            }
        }

        // Do we need to update our vector?         
        BellmanFord();
    }

    public void BellmanFord()
    {
        int n = nextHop.Length;
        int[] newVector = new int[n];
        int[] newNextHop = new int[n];
        newVector[Id] = 0;
        newNextHop[Id] = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            List<DistanceHop> DistanceAndNextHop = new List<DistanceHop>();
            if (i != Id)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    if (j != Id)
                    {
                        int x = Vector[Id, j];
                        int y = Vector[j, i];
                        DistanceAndNextHop.Add(new DistanceHop(x + y, j));
                    }
                }
                int a = DistanceAndNextHop.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Distance)).Min();
                int hop = -1;
                foreach (var distance in DistanceAndNextHop)
                {
                    hop = distance.GetHopByDistance(a);
                    if (hop != -1) break;
                }
                newVector[i] = a;
                newNextHop[i] = hop;
            }
        }

        bool changed = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (Vector[Id, i] > newVector[i])
            {
                Vector[Id, i] = newVector[i];
                nextHop[i] = newNextHop[i];
                changed = true;
            }
        }
        // if our vector changed, we have to send it to our neighbors
        if (changed) SendVector();
    }
}

class DistanceHop
{
    public int Distance { get; set; }
    public int NextHop { get; set; }

    public DistanceHop(int distance, int nextHop)
    {
        Distance = distance;
        NextHop = nextHop;
    }

    public int GetHopByDistance(int distance)
    {
        if (distance == Distance) return NextHop;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your class smells like a *god class* - try to find a name that will describe the intention of the class (too me it must be RouterInformationDistanceCalculator) and if it gets too long you have a good indicator for that.

Comment: Distance calculation can be done with [A*Search Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) and I posted a [complete sample](http://www.mycsharp.de/wbb2/thread.php?postid=3797823=#post3797823) (german site) with a generic implementation. You can take it as an example how to structure your classes